# Wordpress + Remote Database = Error Establishing Connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to move my database offsite to a separate dedicated box which my wordpress can connect to remotely. I have already done the requisite dumps, imports, and permissions. After changing wp-config's DB_HOST from localhost to the remote IP, I am getting the big bold "ERROR ESTABLISHING CONNECTION" message and a blank page.

I can currently access the remote mysql database from linux commandline using:

```
mysql -u USER -p -h REMOTE_IP
```

and everything works fine. so I know all the permissions are set up, and everything is in order.

Yet when I put the same credentials into the silly wordpress config, it's not working. Any ideas? I turned on mysql error logging but nothing is showing up from these failed attempts.

Comment: What exactly is your config file code? `define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');`

Comment: Are you executing "mysql -u USER -p -h REMOTE_IP" from the machine that WordPress is on or from the machine that database is on? What I am aiming at is maybe the database is not configured for remote access.

Answer (score 3):

This is old but I'll reply anyway in case anyone comes across this.

I had a similar problem earlier. My config file was correct and my database was remotely accessible from my box running apache, like your situation. I figured the problem had to be that apache wasn't allowed to make a connection to the database... or something along those lines.

That being said, try running this if SELinux is enabled:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the IP of the remote database server for wp-config.php, i.e.:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XX');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Locate the mysql config file `/etc/mysql/my.conf`.
2. change the bind address to `0.0.0.0`

then try this 
`mysql -h your_target_ip -u user_name -p`

If it shows any error please replay here I will help you